# Is it possible to mount a an output f the linux command onto a docker target?

Tags: docker, ssh, credentials

I am trying to achieve something like this. I have access to my private key as a environment variable and I am trying to access it in docker container.

```
docker run -v /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa:$MY_PRIVATE_KEY MyImage
```

or

```
docker run -v /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa:$(echo $MY_PRIVATE_KEY) MyImage
```

Comment: Docker options like `-v /host/path:/container/path` need to come _before_ the image name `MyImage`; otherwise they're interpreted as the command to run (or passed as arguments to the entrypoint).

Answer (score 0):

The order of your command is wrong.

You can find correct syntax with description for `docker run` in [Docker reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/).

The general form of the `docker run` command looks like:

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

Your command has to be:

```
docker run -v /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa:${MY_PRIVATE_KEY} MyImage
```

After the `MyImage` phrase you can specify a tag for the image (by using a colon) or a command which should be executed in the container (by using a whitespace).

Comment: Thank you for correcting my syntax, but still it is not the question.